# Product of divisors plus one

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

For which positive integers $n$ is the following property satisfied: 
$$\prod_{k|n}k\text{ divides } \prod_{k|n}(k+1)$$

For $n$ up to $15$, only $n=1$ and $n=2$ work. If $n>2$ is prime then $n$ does not divide $2(n+1)$. For other $n$, it looks like the greatest prime divisor of $n$ will appear with greater exponent in $\prod_{k|n}k$ than in $\prod_{k|n}(k+1)$.

Comment: I haven't devoted any effort to the question, but for $n \leq 20000$ the only working $n$ are $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Just a remark $\prod_{d\mid n}d=n^{\sigma_0(n)/2}$, where $\sigma_0(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}1$. I don't know if it could be useful.